# Unable to create a new Apple ID with previously unused email address

Tags: apple-id

I am trying to create new Apple ID, but when I enter the details it shows me an error saying my email is valid and ok but it's not available even though I didn't use this email before for any Apple ID.

According to documentation I checked, "not available" means it would be used or associated with any other Apple ID but when I try to sign in and use the option that I forgot the password it shows me that there is no record for this ID.

What do these errors mean?

Comment: Do you use that email address as a secondary or recovery address for another account? That would prevent its use.

Comment: I have almost the same problem. I want to _change_ my main email address. The email I want to enter used to be my safety address. Though I removed this address, the apple website keeps telling me it is unavailable. I'll let it sit a day or two (maybe some cache must be updated somewhere) and I'll let you know whether waiting does anything good.